# Convert MediaFile to Blob

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
this.mediaCapture.captureVideo()
 .then(
   (data: MediaFile[]) => console.log(data),
   (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
 );
```

I wonder how can I convert the mediafile to blob. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
let blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], { type: 'application/json' });
```

you can change the type based on the requirement

Comment: Is it applicable on type mp4? I already tried it but it's not converting into blob